# Derivative of distance along a smooth curve

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, arc-length, metric-geometry

I am struggling to solve the following problem from 'Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds' by *John M. Lee*

> $(M,g)$ be a connected Riemannian manifold. $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to M$ be a smooth curve then $$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{d_g(\gamma(0),\gamma(t))}{t}=|\dot\gamma(0)|_g$$

I was able to show that $$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{d_g(\gamma(0),\gamma(t))}{t}\le \lim_{t\to0+}\frac{l(\gamma|_{[0,t]})}{t}=\lim_{t\to0-}\frac{l(\gamma|_{[t,0]})}{t}=|\dot\gamma(0)|_g$$
Here $l(\cdot)$ denotes length of the curve.

Then I tried to contradict assuming  $$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{d_g(\gamma(0),\gamma(t))}{t}>|\dot\gamma(0)|_g$$
but failed to complete the argument.

Am I doing anything wrong? Please help. Some hints would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is very hard to guess what tools you have available to you. Has Lee covered geodesic polar coordinates (Riemann normal coordinates)?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I know all those.

Comment: Have you tried using that, then? :)

Comment: I figured it out. thank you, sir @TedShifrin

Comment: That's fantastic, @Noob. Why don't you post your solution as an answer?  I'll be glad to upvote it if it's right.

Comment: there is a mistake in this question which I have made . The limit doesn't necessarily exist for $t\to0$ it exists for $t\to 0+$. I misinterpreted the question given in the book.

Comment: Nah. That can't be right. Just change the curve to $\tilde\gamma(t)=\gamma(-t)$.

Comment: even $\lim_{t\to0-}\frac{l(\gamma|_{[t,0]})}{t}=|\dot\gamma(0)|_g$ is not true. It should be $\lim_{t\to0-}\frac{l(\gamma|_{[t,0]})}{t}=-|\dot\gamma(0)|_g$

Comment: What I observed is if $t<0$ function $d(\gamma(0),\gamma(t))$ is decreasing and increasing when $t>0$. Here we are looking at the derivative of $d(\gamma(0),\gamma(t))$, isn't it?@TedShifrin

Comment: LOL, oh, yeah, you're absolutely correct. Good catch.

Answer (score 5):

There is a severe mistake in this question, I misinterpreted the notation in the book due to my ignorance. It was after sir Ted Shifrin's comment that i noticed it (thanks).
The actual question is the following:

> $(M,g)$ be a connected Riemannian manifold. $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to M$ be a smooth curve then $$\lim_{t\to0+}\frac{d_g(\gamma(0),\gamma(t))}{t}=|\dot\gamma(0)|_g$$

The limit doesn't necessarily exist for $t\to0$ please follow the above discussion with sir Ted Shifrin for justification. Also one should notice
$$|\dot\gamma(0)|_g=\lim_{t\to0+}\frac{l(\gamma|_{[0,t]})}{t}\not=\lim_{t\to0-}\frac{l(\gamma|_{[t,0]})}{t}=-|\dot\gamma(0)|_g$$

---

Now here is the proof that works, which I was able to figure out only after Ted mentioned normal coordinates in the comment--

For $t$ small enough in a normal neighbourhood around $\gamma(0)$ we have
$$\gamma(t)=(x^1(t),\dots,x^n(t))$$

Now $$d(\gamma(0),\gamma(t))=\sqrt{\sum (x^i(t))^2}$$
Therefore
$$\lim_{t\to0+}\frac{d_g(\gamma(0),\gamma(t))}{t}=\lim_{t\to0+}\frac{\sqrt{\sum (x^i(t))^2}}{t}=\lim_{t\to0+}\sqrt{\sum \left(\frac{x^i(t)}{t}\right)^2}=\sqrt{\sum (\dot x^i(0))^2}=|\dot\gamma(0)|_g$$

Comment: Write $\gamma(t)=(x^1(t),\dots,x^n(t))$. At the end, you need $\dot x^i(0)$.

Comment: I have editted it accordingly. Thanks @TedShifrin